# How to use Font-Awesome with the NbActionComponent?

Tags: nebular

I am successfully using a mixture of the default Eva icons and Font Awesome icons with Nebular 4 in Ngx-Admin. I can configure both `NbIcon` and `NbMenuItem` components to use either the default Eva icons or Font-awesome icons using the "pack" config parameter.

There does not seem to be a 'pack' attribute for `NbActionComponent` and it also does not accept the `icon` attribute being supplied in the format: `{icon: 'globe', pack:'font-awesome'}` (which works for menu items).

How exactly do I set an `nb-action` to use any icon not in the default icon pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

icon attribute takes an icon name or an icon object, have you tried:

```
<nb-action [icon]="{icon: 'file', pack: 'solid'}"></nb-action>
```

Comment: I had tried supplying the icon definition in that format as a variable from the angular component, but it didn't work and so I discounted trying it direct in the HTML. Trying your example does work! Thank you Jeremy